# Toggle mesh renderer with a Unity event in Animator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi guys I'm pretty new to unity and I am trying to make an animation where some of the meshes within a prefab only appear ~halfway through the animation.

I have added an event at the desired time within animator but I cant figure out exactly what code I need to execute to turn the mesh renderer on.

So far I have this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class toggleMesh : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Renderer rend;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        rend.enabled = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void toggleMeshR()
    {
        rend.enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Any help with this would be appreciated

Comment: Please don't tag C# questions as Unityscript questions. They are different languages.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an animation as you said, put an animation event on the frame(time) you desire to call your toggleMeshR().

When you right click on timeline of animation, you can create animation events.
More information: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AnimationWindowEvent.html